# Why won't my absolute-positioned div stay at the top level in IE?

Tags: css, css-position, html

I have a test site at [capitalcitysc](http://wms-clients.com/capitalcitysc/) and right over the header there should be the soccer club logo named logo.png. Shows fine in Firefox, but IE and Chrome do not. I don't have an easy way to test the css as I use a Mac with Firebug and my test PC has IE6 installed but no developer tools. I have tried z-index and moving the div's position in the header file but have had no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function` at `wms-clients.com:55`, which is `$(document).ready(function(){ `

Comment: Google Chrome sez: You have no `$` function! I can't see it in debugger, so I'm assuming there is a problem with the jQuery include or something similar.

Comment: I'll look into this too josh.trow, I appreciate the feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’ve actually got an HTML error: you’re missing the closing `>` on the logo’s `<a>` tag:

```
<div id="logo"><a href="http://wms-clients.com/capitalcitysc/"<img src="http://wms-clients.com/capitalcitysc/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/logo.png" /></a></div>
```

Stuff like this is where [validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwms-clients.com%2Fcapitalcitysc%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) really helps.

Comment: Dang beat me to it @Paul but +1

Comment: @pixelbobby: I’ve found that when you’re 50 points away from 10K, you really start wanting to answer questions fast :) DAMN YOU ATWOOD

Comment: Thanks Paul, that was it. I used to validate every site I was working on but fell out of the habit. Time to get back in :)

Comment: @drew: You’re most welcome. Yeah, it’s silly little errors like this that I think of when folks say that validation is pointless — it spots this stuff way easier than I can. (That said, editors with code highlighting can help too.)